# How to make a registration and login form with gui in python

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt6

**Hi Everyone**
Please help me!

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QTextBrowser, QTextEdit
from register import create_user
from login import verify_user
from encrypt import encrypt_message, decrypt_message
from steganography import encode, decode

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Technoeed Chat")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.setup_login_page()

    def setup_login_page(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.username_input = QLineEdit()
        self.password_input = QLineEdit()
        self.password_input.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.EchoMode.Password)

        login_button = QPushButton("Login")
        login_button.clicked.connect(self.login)

        register_label = QLabel("Don't have an account? Register below:")
        register_button = QPushButton("Register")
        register_button.clicked.connect(self.setup_registration_page)

        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Username:"))
        layout.addWidget(self.username_input)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Password:"))
        layout.addWidget(self.password_input)
        layout.addWidget(login_button)
        layout.addWidget(register_label)
        layout.addWidget(register_button)

        if self.central_widget.layout():
            old_layout = self.central_widget.layout()
            while old_layout.count():
                item = old_layout.takeAt(0)
                if item.widget():
                    item.widget().deleteLater()

        self.central_widget.setLayout(layout)

    def setup_registration_page(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.new_username_input = QLineEdit()
        self.new_password_input = QLineEdit()
        self.new_password_input.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.EchoMode.Password)

        register_button = QPushButton("Register")
        register_button.clicked.connect(self.register)

        back_button = QPushButton("Back to Login")
        back_button.clicked.connect(self.setup_login_page)

        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Choose a Username:"))
        layout.addWidget(self.new_username_input)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Choose a Password:"))
        layout.addWidget(self.new_password_input)
        layout.addWidget(register_button)
        layout.addWidget(back_button)

        if self.central_widget.layout():
            old_layout = self.central_widget.layout()
            while old_layout.count():
                item = old_layout.takeAt(0)
                if item.widget():
                    item.widget().deleteLater()

        self.central_widget.setLayout(layout)



    def login(self):
        username = self.username_input.text()
        password = self.password_input.text()

        user_data = verify_user(username, password)

        if user_data is not None:
            success, user_data = user_data
            self.setup_chat_page()
        else:
            error_label = QLabel("Invalid username or password.")
            layout = self.central_widget.layout()
            layout.addWidget(error_label)


    def register(self):
        new_username = self.new_username_input.text()
        new_password = self.new_password_input.text()

        success, user_data = create_user(new_username, new_password)

        if success:
            self.setup_chat_page()

        else:
            error_label = QLabel("Username already exists. Please choose a different username.")
            layout = self.central_widget.layout()
            layout.addWidget(error_label)

    def send_message(self):
        message = self.message_input.toPlainText()
        encrypted_message = encrypt_message(message)

    def receive_message(self, encrypted_message):
        decrypted_message = decrypt_message(encrypted_message)

        self.chat_box.append(decrypted_message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I have some issues in this code. When I try to register the output is: QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on QWidget "", which already has a layout.
And second issue when I try to log in the output in the terminal is: Login successful!, but in the GUI: invalid username or password.

What can be the problem

I need to make a GUI with registration and login form

Comment: Don't try to set a different layout on the same widget. Instead create *pages* (as separate QWidgets that will act as containers) and add them to a [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstackedwidget.html) that will be the central widget.